# Convergence/Divergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{3^n+4^n}$ Using Comparison Test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Use the comparison test to show if the series converges/diverges?

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{3^n+4^n}$

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{3^n+4^n} \leq \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{4^n}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}=\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

So it does not go to infinity.

furthermore, since for all $i$: $\frac{2^i}{3^i+4^i} >0$ we get $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{3^n+4^n}>0$$ so it does not go to minus infinity as well.

Conclusion: it converges.

Comment: It converges but the fact that does not go to $ -\infty$, albeit correct, it's useless. The way to show it is that, since all terms are positive, then the sum is increasing => it admits limit. Then the inequality show that the sum is bounded, and this implies that the limit is finite hence converges :-)

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:*

$\dfrac{2^n}{3^n+4^n}\leq\dfrac{2^n}{3^n}$

Does $\dfrac{2^n}{3^n}$ converge?

Comment: yes, r=2/3 < 1; could I have used (2/4)^n with the same logic? you just picked the dominant terms correct?

Comment: Yes, so since $\dfrac{2^n}{3^n}$ is convergent, we have by the Comparison Test that our original series is convergent. We would have come to the same conclusion even if I had chosen to bound our original series by $\dfrac{2^n}{4^n}$ instead.